# How do I add an entry to eclipse Package Explorer context menu to start a TextEditor?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to add an entry to the Package Explorer pop-up context menu that opens a modified version of a file in an editor when the entry is selected.

I am using Eclipse Indigo on a Fedora 15 laptop.

Here's a very specific question that may be adequately well-focused, and might provide the help I need to tackle the general problem I have.

Eclipse provides a sample plugin named org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool, which can be set up from the Help->Welcome page.

This plugin defines an editor named ReadmeEditor.java.  It also defines an extension point "org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus" in plugin.xml.  When you use this action from the eclipse Project Explorer view on a file with the suffix ".readme", you just get a little pop-up window.

How can I change the readmetool plugin so that when you select the above-defined Project Explorer menu item on a foo.readme file, you instead get a new ReadmeEditor in eclipse, with foo.readme in it??

The more specific project need I am struggling with is as follows:

- From the Package Explorer, navigate to a file.
- Right-click the file to get a pop-up context menu
- See a new entry "Version view"
- On selecting that entry, find the file, run it through an external program to create a temporary file, and display the contents of that temporary file in a new TextEditor window.  (And, don't leave an orphan temporary file around after it is no longer needed.)

I have some of the above pieces in place; I augmented the MultiPageEditor example so that it does the work of running the external program, creating the temporary file, and opening the temporary file in a text editor.

However, the only way I can currently access that functionality is to select the "Open With" option in the pop-up context window for the file in the Project Explorer, and go to "Other" within that window and select my new editor option.

So, where I am stuck at the moment is how to add the right magic to plugin.xml so that I get a new option on the Project Manager pop-up context window, and connect that with a new TextEditor window.

This seems very much like what the vanilla "Open" option would do, and it seems like this should be a pretty basic thing to do within eclipse.  Any examples and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Greg

Answer (score 6):

Here is a terse but complete example of setting up and using a project.  (Scouring the net, there was much advice about eclipse, but it tended to be rather splintered and piecemeal, and when I was struggling to solve my problem it would have been helpful to have a complete, self-contained HOWTO.  So, this is that..)

This recipe assumes you are using Eclipse Indigo or Juno with:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment.

To confirm the above from within eclipse, see

```
Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software
```

1. start up Ecipse Indigo, with a fresh, empty workspace:

   ```
   you, before starting eclipse:
             move or delete ~/eclipse.d/popup_workspace.d
             mkdir -p ~/eclipse.d/popup_workspace.d
   start eclipse:  eclipse
   eclipse:  "Select a workspace"
   you:      "Browse", navigate to above-created popup_workspace.d; "OK" "OK"
   eclipse:  "Welcome to Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"
   you:      select "Workbench"
   ```
2. create a new project, using the Plug-in Project as a handy starting place:

   ```
   you:      File -> New -> Project
   eclipse:  "Select a wizard:
   you:      Plug-in Development -> Plug-in Project;  Next>
   eclipse:  "Plug-in Project"
   you:      Project name:  org.mypopup.popup_editor  Next>
   eclipse:  "Content"
   you:      Next>
   eclipse:  "Templates"
   you:      Plug-in with a popup menu                Finish
   eclipse:  "This kind of project is associated with the
             Plug-in Development perspective..."
   you:      Yes
   ```
3. in "Package Explorer, navigate to NewActions.java and double-click to open:

   ```
   org.mypopup.popup_editor
       -> src
           -> org.mypopup.popup_editor.popup.actions
               -> NewAction.java

   delete entire contents and replace with:

   package org.mypopup.popup_editor.popup.actions;

   import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeSelection;
   import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreePath;
   import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
   import org.eclipse.core.filesystem.EFS;
   import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath;
   import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
   import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
   import org.eclipse.ui.IObjectActionDelegate;
   import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
   import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
   import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
   import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
   import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;

   public class NewAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {
       public NewAction() {
           super();
       }

       public void run(IAction action) {
           try {
               IWorkbenchWindow window =
                       PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

               ISelection selection = window.getSelectionService()
                       .getSelection("org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer");

               TreePath[] paths = ((TreeSelection) selection).getPaths();
               TreePath p = paths[0];
               Object last = p.getLastSegment();

               if (last instanceof IFile) {
                   IPath ipath = ((IFile) last).getLocation();

                   IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

                   IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page,
                           EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(ipath));
               }
           } catch (Exception blah) {
           }
       }

       public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) { }

       public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) { }
   }
   ```
4. add dependencies to the project to be able to resolve imports:

   ```
   in Package Explorer, navigate to and open META-INF -> MANIFEST.MF

   Select "Dependencies" tab along the bottom of the resulting
   "org.mypopup.plugin_editor" window

   "Add..."; "Select a Plug-in:" enter org.eclipse.core.filesystem; "OK"
   "Add..."; "Select a Plug-in:" enter org.eclipse.ui.ide; "OK"

   File -> Save my.popup.popup_editor
   ```
5. run the new project, with a fresh empty target directory:

   ```
   outside of eclipse, browse to the directory containing popup_workspace.d,
   in this case ~/eclipse.d, and if a folder "runtime-EclipseApplication"
   exists, move it or delete it.

   right-click META-INF -> MANIFEST.MF, select Run As -> Eclipse Application

   in new eclipse window:
   eclipse:  "Welcome to Eclipse"
   you:      select "Workbench"
   you:      File -> New -> Project
   eclipse:  "Select a wizard"
   you:      General -> Project              Next>
   eclipse:  "Project"
   you:      project name popup_test         Finish
   you:      in Project Explorer, right-click popup_test, select New -> File
   eclipse:  "File"
   you:      File name:  test_file1          Finish
   you:      enter a little text in test_file1, File -> Save; File -> Close
   ```
6. the big moment:  open the file with your new pop-up menu entry:

   ```
   in Project Explorer, right-click popup_test -> test_file1
   select New Submenu -> New Action
   ```

Comment: There's a util function for retrieving selection:
TreeSelection selection = ((TreeSelection) HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelectionChecked(event));

Answer (score 2):

The `readmetool` example already provides a context menu action for .readme files:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
  <objectContribution
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
        nameFilter="*.readme"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool">
     <action
           label="%PopupMenus.action"
           icon="$nl$/icons/ctool16/openbrwsr.gif"
           helpContextId="org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool.open_browser_action_context"
           class="org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool.PopupMenuActionDelegate"
           menubarPath="additions"
           enablesFor="1"
           id="org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool.action1">
     </action>
  </objectContribution>
  ...
</extension>
```

It is named `Show Readme Action` but you can rename it to `Version view` by editing plugin.properties which contain the corresponding label names:

```
PopupMenus.action = &Version view
```

Then you only need to edit `PopupMenuActionDelegate` and change its implementation to do what you want:

```
public class PopupMenuActionDelegate implements IObjectActionDelegate {

    public void run(IAction action) {
        // invoke the external tool and open the result in a new editor
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful suggestion.  What I am struggling with now is what goes inside the "run" action above to get a TextEditor to come up.  At the moment I would be happy to create a dummy file "/tmp/samplefile" and pop up an editor in eclipse that contains the contents of that file.

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_a_file_outside_the_workspace%3F

Comment: Thanks!  That page refers to an object "window" that I don't know how to find or initialize:  "IWorkbenchPage page=  window.getActivePage();"  Do I have to create a new editor window somehow?

Comment: IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

Comment: `try {
            IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            File f = new File("/tmp/testum");
            IPath ipath = new Path(f.getAbsolutePath());
            IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
            IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(ipath));
        } catch (Exception blah) {
         System.err.println("Exception!");
        }`

Comment: rgerganov, huge/many thanks for your help.  I finally have something that is starting to work.  I added code snippets based on your suggestions into the run method of the PopupMenuActionDelegate().  I will mark your answer as accepted to give you karma, but I will also add an answer so that I can put the example code into a format that is easier for others to see.  (I tried to add the code to a comment, but without much success.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small, self-contained example of getting an editor window to open in response to selection of a pop-up window option.  As a test, it opens a file with a hard-wired name.

```
public void run(IAction action) {
    try {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        File f = new File("/tmp/testum");
        IPath ipath = new Path(f.getAbsolutePath());
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(ipath));
    } catch (Exception blah) {
        System.err.println("Exception!");
    }
}
```